# Flycheck elisp "There should be two spaces after period"

Tags: flycheck, sentences

Is there any way to disable just this one warning?
Two spaces seems like overkill but maybe that is the lisp standard?

Comment: What is your value of option `sentence-end-double-space`? Have you tried setting it to `nil`?

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work with flycheck. Do you know if 2 spaces is a lisp standard?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Lisp. It is a convention for plain text, inherited from typewriter days. [Please read the doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Sentences.html) about `sentence-end-double-space`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE as of 2017-02-14: With [this](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/pull/1199) pull-request merged, now you just have to set `sentence-end-double-space` to `nil` and that's it. More information [here](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1212).

Answer (score 1):

Flycheck uses `checkdoc-current-buffer` to implement the `emacs-lisp-checkdoc` checker which (in general) takes `sentence-end-double-space` into account. However, the checker itself is implemented by calling an emacs subprocess and only passing along the variables whitelisted in `flycheck-emacs-lisp-checkdoc-variables`, which doesn't include `sentence-end-double-space`. You can (but since it's a defconst shouldn't) add `sentence-end-double-space` to `flycheck-emacs-lisp-checkdoc-variables` to pass it along as well:

```
(setq-local flycheck-emacs-lisp-checkdoc-variables (cons 'sentence-end-double-space flycheck-emacs-lisp-checkdoc-variables))
```

Comment: I just tried this, it seems like the right direction from everything else I've read. But this didn't fix the problem. For now I will use 2 spaces. Is that a lisp standard?

Comment: Two spaces after a sentence is a convention in Emacs Lisp, see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/sentence_002dend.html. The above `setq-local` command and setting `sentence-end-double-space` to `nil` followed by `flycheck-buffer` removed the warning here.

Comment: @Wieland, what's exactly `flycheck-buffer`? I don't understand. I tried adding `(setq-local flycheck-emacs-lisp-checkdoc-variables (cons 'sentence-end-double-space flycheck-emacs-lisp-checkdoc-variables))` plus setting `sentence-end-double-space` to nil. The missing piece is `flycheck-buffer`. But I don't know what do you mean by that? thanks!

Comment: `flycheck-buffer` is an interactive function, so you can call it with `M-x`. However, my pull request to respect the value of `sentence-end-double-space` by default has been merged a few days ago (https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/pull/1199), so this should work automatically with flycheck versions that contain it!